# Finding vectors

Tags: vectors

In maths we are currently doing vectors, and whilst I understand the basics I have no idea as of how to find the answer (all answers must be expressed in terms of x and y) to the current question (b and c)

[image: question]

I can do a quite easily, you just find a path from A to B which is part of a vector; so the answer is $-x+y$ (or $y-x$).

However to find AM (question b) neither of the given vectors have the same gradient so I cant't figure out at all how to get there. I thought the answer might have something to do with finding an "average" between the two vectors (maybe $-x+2/3(x+y)$ or something) to get to the middle but I am not sure.

What am I missing (apologies if the answer is very obvious!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from $A$ to $M$ is the same as going one third of the way from $A$ to $B$. In symbols:

$$\vec{AM} = \frac{1}{3}\vec{AB}$$

You already know what $\vec{AB}$ is, and so you now know what $\vec{AM}$ is:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{AM} &=& \frac{1}{3}\vec{AB} \\ \\ \\
&=& \frac{1}{3}({\bf y}-{\bf x}) \\ \\ \\
&=& \frac{1}{3}{\bf y} - \frac{1}{3}{\bf x}
\end{eqnarray*}

To find $\vec{OM}$ you need to go from $O$ to $A$ to $M$:

$$\vec{OM} = \vec{OA} + \vec{AM}$$

Can you do this yourself?

Comment: Thank you!!! I completely get it now :) Just one question, I understand that $y-x$ is for AB, but that seems a lot longer than going directly from points A to B (if you see what I mean) - are they still equivalent?

Comment: Also to answer the question, would it be as simle as adding $x$ to $1/3(y-x)$?

Comment: If you were to follow the actual paths one-by-one then the distance you would travel is indeed longer that the distance between where you started and where you finished. But it's the final result that you're interested in. It's the same as $3-5=3+(-5)=-2$. If you walked along the number-line from $0$ to $+3$ and then from $+3$ to $-5$ then you would have traveled a distance of $11$, even though you're only $5$ from where you started.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now

Comment: @user135285 I'm glad that I could help :o)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- For (b) you want to go a third of the way from A to B
- For (c) You want to go from O to A to M